# Is any performance gained by using an if/else statement for an assignment?

Tags: c

I have simple question that I just wasn't sure about.

Consider the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void turnOn(int *power);
static void turnOff(int *power);

int main(void)
{
    int powerIsOn = 0;


    turnOn(&powerIsOn);
    printf("Power Status: %d\n", powerIsOn);

    turnOff(&powerIsOn);
    printf("Power Status: %d\n", powerIsOn);

    return 0;
}


static void turnOn(int *power)
{
    if (!*power)
        *power = 1;
    // Or
    //*power = 1;
    return;
}

static void turnOff(int *power)
{
    if (*power)
        *power = 0;
    // Or
    // *power = 0;
    return;
}
```

I know that this wouldn't cause a noticeable difference in something this small. But In methods that do some sort of assignment, is it more efficient to check if a Boolean or whatever is already true/false before re-assigning it's value?

For example, the `turnOn()` function is set to only turn the power on if it is off. Would it be any slower or faster just to set it to 1 regardless of the value?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: unless you are on an (exotic) platform where a memory write is *much* more expensive than a memory read, you'll most likely gain nothing from such "optimisation". It's much more likely for it to be counter-productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case your code accessing the memory, it does inside of "if" and it does when you assign it to 1. In addition "if" statement adds few more lines to the binary code, so if you can just assign without using "if", it is better and more efficient.

```
if (!*power)    #one memory access and addition if actions
    *power = 1; #one more memory access and assignment
```

Looking at the compiled assembly code for

```
static void turnOn(int *power)
{
    if (!*power)
        *power = 1;
    return;
}
```

We will see the next code

```
turnOn:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L4
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        nop
.L4:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And for:

```
static void turnOn(int *power)
{
    *power = 1;
    return;
}
```

Next code:

```
turnOn:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

It seem to me that the machine will run more operations in the first case.
I was using the https://godbolt.org/ compiler.

Comment: Reading the value of an address in memory is a different operation than writing a value to it.

Comment: Indeed, and yet, reading the value requires access to the memory. If it can be spared, then why not? And addition action to perform the if operation can cost more than the value assignment, depends on the compiler.

Comment: As it depends on how compiler will generate the code, I think it is not right to say "it is better to remove the check". Besides that, if the check returns false a considerable number of times, it **can** ending up saving cpu cycles as I think it is what OP was concerned about.

Comment: The assembly code will be implementation-specific buddy. You can not assume what the compiler you are using outputs is relevant to check it because, as I said, A- others compiler can output a different code and B- it will depend on how much this flag check in `if` will be relevant.

Comment: I edited the answer, take a look and maybe it will convince you.

Comment: Oh, and godbolt **is not** a compiler. Saying you "compiled" the code using godbolt means nothing.

Comment: Ok, I accept what you saying. In any case, I checked it on my computer and run the two variants on loop of 100000000 iterations and compared the time. On my computer it took 25.5 seconds on average to run the first variant and 21.1 seconds to run the seconds and the results stays much similar between the measurements. I accept that different implementation may behave different. For this specific case, I am convinced that it is better without if.

Comment: For your specific scenario it is faster without the flag check, but imagine if 99% of the times when `turnOn` is called the condition on `if` returns false and the assignment is not executed?

Answer (score 1):

Both operations involve accessing variables and therefore depend on memory management. Assignment involves re-writing to memory, and therefore is more "expensive" than comparing constant values (booleans, or `1` and `0`).

With that being said, with modern hardware these differences are negligible and therefore considered [micro-optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627760/whats-more-expensive-comparison-or-assignment), which aren't recommended.

Comment: It all depends on the memory management method. It might improve run-time, but I'd use it only if there are *a lot* of variables (relatively to the memory size), which is probably not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can only be answered profiling the code in a specific scenario.

Reading a variable in C **can** be more efficient than assigning a value to it if the compiler generates code that reads the value directly (however it is depends on the implementation of a given compiler).

However to determine whether it executes faster or not it is circumstantial e.g. if the both functions are called sequentially a lot of times then the additional `if` statement you created is useless as the condition will always return true and will generate additional instructions (and by that the CPU will spend additional clocks executing them) to perform a check that is always returning true. I would say it really need to be profiled and is context-dependent.

Comment: Reading, comparing, and assigning can be faster than simply assigning?  That would be an interesting system...

Comment: If we assume that the `if` statement OP wrote is possible to be executed faster than its embedded statement, then it is just logical to assume that it is **possible** for this implementation to end up executing faster. Unless you are implying the `if` statement **can not** be executed faster than its embedded statement; is that what you are saying?

Comment: No. I'm saying it's almost certainly impossible to do **A then B then C** faster than just **C** alone.  Your entire premise is that it's possible to do **A then B then C** faster than just **C**.  Simply because it's impossible to prove a negative, I'm simply saying you have one hell of a gigantic burden of proof to overcome to substantiate your claim.